# MAG: Resetting character, what about medals?

Tags: ps3, mag

After gaining final level I will be able to reset my character to start working for new PMC. Will this make me also loose my statistics, medals and ribbons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will keep all your medals, ribbons and statistics. You will also keep all your money and the re-sale cost of any weapons/equipment you own. Obviously, you will restart at level 1 so you will not keep your skill points. You also get a nice XP bonus every game.